# ALE Error and warning highlighting gets disabled when termguicolors is enabled

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, highlight, plugin-ale

I have the [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) extension installed, and would like it to highlight errors and warnings, however when `:set termguicolors` is enabled, the

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

```
set termguicolors    
highlight ALEWarning ctermbg=DarkMagenta
```

[image]

```
set notermguicolors    
highlight ALEWarning ctermbg=DarkMagenta
```

[image]

As you can see, when termguicolors is enabled, ALE is unable to errors or warnings.

Is this just a limitation of the plugin? If not, I would like some help as to how to solve it.

If it helps, I am using `NVIM v0.4.2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read from [`:h 'termguicolors'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27termguicolors%27):

```
'termguicolors' 'tgc'   boolean (default off)
            global
    Enables 24-bit RGB color in the TUI.  Uses "gui" :highlight
    attributes instead of "cterm" attributes.
```

So your highlighting command can not work since it doesn't provide a `guifg` attribute. I think the following should do the trick:

```
highlight ALEWarning guibg=DarkMagenta
```

If it doesn't you might check that you have an ISO-8613-3 compatible terminal as specified in the help.